# jquery not parsing data held in data attribute

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse data held in an data attribute defined as follows

HTML

```
<div data-details="{'value':'2.38', 'image':tesco.png }"></div>
```

jquery

```
var details = $(this).data('details');
```

when trying to parse the json as

```
$.parseJSON(details)
```

it returns in console

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Any guidance is much apreciated.

*edit even when html declared as (all variables wrapped in single quotes)

```
 <div class="transaction-panel matched" data-details="{'value':'2.38', 'image':'tesco.png' }" ></div>
```

the same error is reurned

Answer (score 4):

Your `details` is *not* valid JSON, so `$.parseJSON` can't read it.  You need to use *double quotes* around your keys and your (string) values.  Valid JSON needs *double quotes*.

```
<div data-details='{"value":2.38, "image":"tesco.png"}'></div>
```

Note: You can use either single or double quotes for HTML attributes.

As noted by [@Vohuman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916350/jquer-not-parsing-data-held-in-data-attribute#comment42381392_26916399), when you do `$(this).data('details')`, jQuery will automagically parse the JSON for you (it will detect that it's JSON, then parse it), you don't need `$.parseJSON`.

Here's a demo [@swatkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916350/jquer-not-parsing-data-held-in-data-attribute#comment42381470_26916399) made: http://jsfiddle.net/dpqpL9kv/

Comment: It should be noted that `data` method tries to parse the JSON, so `$.parseJSON` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Vohuman: I forgot about that, you're right!  Let me add that to the answer.

Comment: it doesn't work when variable names and values are wrapped in quotes returning the same error, using data isn't return the data as an object but as a string

Comment: @BarryHamilton: Probably because of what @Vohuman said.  `$(this).data('details')` will parse the JSON for you.  You don't need `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: $(this).data('details') is returning the json as a string not an object

Comment: @BarryHamilton: What version of jQuery are you using?  If it's a string, then what error does `$.parseJSON` give you?

Comment: @BarryHamilton: Did you use *double quotes* around your keys/values, like I show in the answer?